# google maps api get countries and cities

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can i have autocomplete with ajax to get countries from google maps api.
When someone type "United" to search on google maps api for that country and to show results for similar ?

Can you give me example, or link to that solution for google maps api ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the [Google Places Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete). Here is a [blog post to get you going](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/05/faster-address-entry-with-google-places.html).